# Mysql second level queries

Tags: mysql

I am in a learning way of  mysql and want help to know where i can find pure mysql unsolved queries. Stackoverflow is very much helpfull in this concern but most of stackoverflow mysql queries are not pure mysql query.Most of them conected to php etc.
Give the links in reply where i can get high level practise queries.
I previously have many links b

Comment: Whatever language is associated with mysql, the queries remain the same...

Comment: Questions here should be primarily related to some question in programming. You better not use Stackoverflow to find MySQL queries as assignments as they are generally related to some particular context(I doubt how useful they would be to teach someone mysql). You could Google for some queries or use a book.

Comment: @Alok: I know basics of mysql, now i want some profesional level of questions to solve, which can be easily found on stackoverflow.

Comment: @Eric : but php have many more things which you cannot done in mysql and when i try to search mysql taged question on stack overflow ,it shows php+mysql question which are out of scope for mysql.

Comment: @Ankit: Everything you do concerning mysql inside php scripts can be done directly into mysql.  The best way to make progress in mysql is to install such a database, search for examples on the net and make you own database, query, update, insert, delete into it !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Pure*** MySQL queries or not different from php's MySQL queries. No matter where the SQL query is written, its behavior remains the same. You can use a frontend like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php) to ease your process of execution, but in the end the queries are the same.

As a side note: Refer to [MySQL tutorials](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx) and your "*Mysql second level queries*" title is wrong as this is not the second level to what you are referring to. :D

Here is a link (a random but useful one) to [advanced SQL tutorial](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/advanced.html)

Comment: i am new on sites like this so i didnot know how to select exect title and the other thing is that i want some tough unsolved mysql queries, which are not required php.

Comment: @Ankit what do you mean "tough"? :D If you refer to complicated then it doesnt matter, You can directly do it in a command prompt for mysql. But in the end php wont slow your execution time. So dont worry

Comment: @Ankit, it doesnt matter as long as its proper SQL. Infact I have a single 1page SQL statement which runs at one go on one of my projects :)

Comment: i am getting what you talking...but i need to improve my skills, so thats why i need more new kind of stuff to practise.

Comment: @Ankit then you would need better tutorials/concepts to learn upon!...  Try to learn 3NF 4NF queries etc, Transactions, procedures, etc.... if u want to use command line to enter these download mysql directly from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ and execute the program